# Как в таблице гугл с помощью MAP/SCAN+LAMBDA установить порядковые номера записей?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, map

Казалось бы, простой случай - установить порядковые номера записей на дату с помощью MAP или SCAN. Перепробовал разные варианты - не получается. Буду благодарен за подсказку.
[Пример здесь](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N2FlhGQ1HN-WE8x-h5zPuvcNBdHN9wnUAf6gIPhT870/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получен анонимный ответ, большая благодарность этому человеку.
=MAP(D2:D; LAMBDA(cell;ЕСЛИ(cell="";;СЧЁТЕСЛИ(D2:cell;cell))))

Только в этой конструкции мне непонятно, как стыкуются D2 и cell в СЧЁТЕСЛИ. Ведь если cell - это D2:D, то D2:cell - D2:D2:D?
Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста